# I want to make the model[i].marker.addListener('click', function() { outside the for loop

Tags: javascript

This code runs but it is not inline with **javascript** best practices, please I want to add the `model[i].marker.addListener('click', function()` outside the for loop but I am having issues.

```
function pushMarkers() {
locInfo = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
for (var i = 0; i < model.length; i++) {
    var loc = model[i].places;
    var title = model[i].title;
    model[i].marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: loc,
        title: title,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        map: map,
        id: i
    });
    console.log(model[i].title);
    model[i].marker.addListener('click', function() {
        console.log('InfoWindow Loop entered');
        toggleBounce(this);
        populateInfoWindow(this, locInfo);
    });
    wikiLink(model[i].marker);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just create a named function to use as the callback, and then use it:

```
function pushMarkers() {

    // Create it
    function mapClickCallback() {
        console.log('InfoWindow Loop entered');
        toggleBounce(this);
        populateInfoWindow(this, locInfo);
    }

    locInfo = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    for (var i = 0; i < model.length; i++) {
        var loc = model[i].places;
        var title = model[i].title;
        model[i].marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: loc,
            title: title,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            map: map,
            id: i
        });
        console.log(model[i].title);
        model[i].marker.addListener('click', mapClickCallback); // <−−−− Use it
        wikiLink(model[i].marker);
    }
}
```

It's fine that the function is defined above `locInfo`, but if you prefer, you can put the function declaration anywhere within `pushMarkers` as long as it's at the top level of that function. (It's defined behavior to use function declarations not at the top level as of ES2015, but there's no need to here and the rules for it are a bit complicated.)

---

Side note: Your code is falling prey to [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*; be sure to declare `locInfo` with `var`.